# Moodle 'core_course_get_contents' not working

Tags: php, web-services, moodle

I'm implementing a simple webservice client in Moodle 3.3 and testing some functions. For some reason, this doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php
$token = '.......';
$domainname = 'http://localhost/moodle';
$functionname = 'core_course_get_contents';
$cid = 5;

/// SOAP CALL
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/soap/server.php'. '?wsdl=1&wstoken=' . $token;

////Do the main soap call
$client = new SoapClient($serverurl);
try {
$resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array($cid));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
if (isset($resp)) {
    print_r($resp);
}
```

I keep getting the error below:

```
SoapFault Object ( [message:protected] => Invalid parameter value detected | ERRORCODE: invalidparameter [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /var/www/html/client.php [line:protected] => 15 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /var/www/html/client.php [line] => 15 [function] => __soapCall [class] => SoapClient [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => core_course_get_contents [1] => Array ( [0] => 5 ) ) ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] => Invalid parameter value detected | ERRORCODE: invalidparameter [faultcode] => Receiver [faultactor] => invalidparameter [detail] => options => Invalid parameter value detected: Only arrays accepted. The bad value is: '' )
```

The documentation for the webservice is:

```
REST (POST parameters)
courseid= int

XML-RPC (PHP structure)
[options] =>
Array
(
[0] =>
Array
(
[name] => string
[value] => string
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code: https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/ae82333cf25219ba627538f7e8de72f0b4028460/course/externallib.php#L49

The expected params are:

- courseid
- options (optional)

So, I would expect the call to look something like:

```
$resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array('courseid' => $cid));
```

If you wanted to specify any of the options, it would look like:

```
$resp = $client->__soapCall($functionname, array('courseid' => $cid, 'options' => [['name' => 'nameofoption', 'value' => 'valuetoset'], ['name' => 'secondoption', 'value' => 'secondvalue]]));
```

Comment: For some reason I don't know, the first call still gives the same error. But the second call with specified options work. I tried just giving the `courseid` on a platform like `SoapUI` which works.